# How to solve $y^{\prime}=\sin y$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve

$$y^{\prime}=\sin y$$

I don't know what to do next $\dfrac{dx}{dy} =\dfrac{ dy}{\sin y}$

Comment: You should instead get $\frac{dy}{\sin y} = dx$.

Answer (score 3):

$$y'=\sin y $$
or, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin y $$
or, $$\frac{dy}{\sin y}=dx $$
or, $$\int \csc y \,\ dy = \int dx$$
or, $$\ln \big|\csc y - \cot y\big|=x+c$$

Answer (score 2):

this is another way depending on the first order linear D.E
$$y^{\prime}=\sin y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin y$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\csc y$$
$$x'=\csc y$$
general form of the first order linear D.E
$$x'+P(y)x=Q(y)$$
or $$P(y)=0$$
$$Q(y)=\csc y$$
then you can solve respect to $x$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin ⁡y$

$\frac{dy}{\sin ⁡y} =1 dx$

$\int \frac{dy}{\sin⁡}y = \int 1 dx  $

Let $\tan ⁡\frac{y}{2}=t$

$y=2 \tan^{-1}t$

$dy=\frac{2}{1+t^2}  dt$

$\sin y=2 \sin\frac{y}{2} \cos\frac{y}{2}$

Use a right angle triangle with sides $1$, $t$, $\sqrt{1+t^2}$  on adjacent, opposite and hypotenuse sides respectively with an angle $\frac y2$.

$\int \dfrac{t^2+1}{2t}×\dfrac{2}{t^2+1}dt=\int1 dx$

$\int\dfrac 1 t  dt= \int 1 dx$

$\ln ⁡t=x+c$

$\ln (⁡\tan ⁡(\frac y 2)) =\ln ⁡e^{x+c} $

$\tan ⁡y=2e^{x+c} $

$y=tan^{-1}⁡(2e^{x+c} )$